# actors' or actor's?

Tags: possessives, double-possessives, genitive-construction

Following text excerpt:

> …it would have been important to work with real-life photographs of
> the **actors'** faces and to…

Is **actors'**, in this case, correct? – Or should it be:

> …it would have been important to work with real-life photographs of
> the **actor's** faces and to…

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the correct place to put the apostrophe here would be after the word: *actors’*. This is because it is talking about multiple actors, making the word **actors**, meaning really you would say *actors’s*, which isn’t grammatically correct, so you remove one S and put the apostrophe to the end:

> …it would have been important to work with real-life photographs of the actors' faces and to…

Is correct.

Comment: I think maybe you intended to write *...meaning really you would say **actors’s***  But because it's effectively "unpronounceable" to have two consecutive /s/ sounds there, we neither enunciate nor write that second instance after the possessive apostrophe.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You’re right, that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably someone *downvoted* you because of that. But now you've corrected the typo, I can upvote you to cancel that out.

Answer (score 3):

**The actors' faces** is correct. For the possessive form of a plural noun ending in 's', the apostrophe is placed at the the end, after the 's'.

> the dogs' tails
>
> the mens' wives
>
> the towns' mayors
>
> the actors' faces

**The actor's faces** would mean the multiple faces possessed by one actor, which would be nonsense, as a person only has one face. However, **the actor's hands** (one actor) and **the actors' hands** (more than one actor) would be possible. Attention to correct use of apostrophes is, as you may perceive, important.

[Apostrophe (The Punctuation Guide)](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/apostrophe.html)

Answer (score 0):

correct: ' faces...

We use apostrophe s (’) to show possession. We add apostrophe s (’) to singular nouns.

actor's face, The boy's dog, girl's doll, my brother's pen

We use apostrophe (’) with plural nouns ending in -s.

Boys' school, Girls' college,

but children's park, women's rights, people's property